# .NET MAUI Plugin.Firebase.iOS does not exist

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I'm using the new Plugin.Firebase plugin to get push notification function working with a clean .NET Maui app-project.

I have installed https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase but for some reson this code is "unreachable" or it does not exist in namespace.

```
#if IOS
using Plugin.Firebase.iOS; <-- Error: code is "unreachable" or it does not exist in namespace
#else
using Plugin.Firebase.Android;
#endif
```

Does anyone else have the same problem or knows any workarount the problem.
Android seems to work as it should to, but I dont understand why. I have compared the source code of both iOS and Android and the namespace should exist in both cases:

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/blob/development/src/Android/CrossFirebase.cs

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/blob/development/src/iOS/CrossFirebase.cs

Comment: It seems like this is a issue with visual studio. Just remove #if from around the namespace. Clean bin & obj and restart Visual studio. Build the project targeting iOS. If it works than again put the namespace within #if

Comment: Tried that, still have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue but with Android.  I haven't set up iOS yet, but I'm assuming I would have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a bug report on it, it refers to another bug which refers to another one.

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/125

Comment: I do understand, the bug part. What I dont understand is "why"... the method is public so why cant I access it? whats restricting my access?

Comment: I was eventually able to work through it.  Follow this guide closely, especially when it comes to editing the project file.  That is where the issue was for me. https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase#net-maui-support

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is the URL with the project editing information: https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-ios-2f4388bf1ac